# Excel 2010 crashes when using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a bit of VBA to compare a date from one column to the dates in another column. My code is:

```vb
Sub ForLoop()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim homenum As Integer
    Dim dif As Long
    Dim clockin As Long
    Dim clockout As Long

    For i = 2 To 18418

        clockin = Cells(i, 4).Value
        homenum = Cells(i, 5).Value
        dif = 100

        For j = 2 To 18418
            clockout = Cells(j, 6).Value
            If Cells(j, 5).Value = homenum & Abs((clockin - clockout) * 24 * 60) < Abs(dif) Then
                dif = Abs((clockin - clockout) * 24 * 60)
            End If
        Next j

        Cells(i, 9).Value = Abs(dif)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Whenever I try to run this, Excel crashes, and I end up having to end the program from Task Manager. I can't find any reason for that in my code. Does anyone have any ideas?

A quick example of the input I'm working with:

[image]

Comment: You have 18417 x 18417 iterations here, that's quite a lot (~340 million). Plus each of those iterations is repeatedly reading and writing to the worksheet, which is rather slow. It's no surprise Excel freezes up.

Comment: `If Cells(j, 5).Value = homenum & Abs((clockin - clockout) * 24 * 60) < Abs(dif) Then` probably want `And` not `&` on that line.

Comment: At first sight this doesn't really look like something that even requires the use of VBA, as opposed to plain old formulas. If you can describe the data and the desired output in neutral terms, a more efficient solution can likely be devised.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have a spreadsheet that includes clock in and clock out times for the months of March and April. I am trying to find the closest clock out time to each clock in time. Does that help?

Comment: What helps is if you [edit] your question to give a minimal example of the problem (sample rows/columns in the form of a table). To a first approximation it sounds like `MATCH` would work just as well, possibly in combination with `MIN`/`MAX` and/or array formulas and/or pre-sorting the input and/or pivot tables. Lots of options. :P

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for telling me. Is that addition useful? I'm trying to fill the minutes overlap column

Answer (score 0):

This should be a lot faster - switched from cell-by-cell reads/writes to using arrays without changing your basic logic.

```vb
Sub ForLoop()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, homenum As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    Dim dif As Long, clockin As Long, clockout As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, data, lr As Long, ub As Long, arrDiffs, d
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always specify a worksheet, even if Activesheet...

    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'last-occupied row in E
    
    data = ws.Range("D2:F" & lr).Value 'read all data as array
    ub = UBound(data, 1)               'get "rows" upper bound
    
    arrDiffs = ws.Range("I2:I" & lr).Value 'read dif column to array
    
    For i = 1 To ub

        clockin = data(i, 1) '1 = D
        homenum = data(i, 2) '2 = E
        dif = 100

        For j = 1 To ub
            If data(j, 2) = homenum Then
                clockout = data(j, 3)  '3 = F 
                d = Abs((clockin - clockout) * 24 * 60)
                If d < dif Then dif = d
            End If
        Next j
        arrDiffs(i, 1) = dif 'update diff array
    Next i
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lr).Value = arrDiffs 'write all diffs back to sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be throwing a Runtime 424 error. Are you sure all the methods you used are compatible with Excel 2010?

Comment: If you're getting an error it useful to say which line and the text of the error (not just the number).  I don't have data to work with so did not test...

Comment: OK I see it `clockout = data(j, 3).Value` should be `clockout = data(j, 3)` - fixed above